# A Deck of Cards

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, exception

I'm a fairly noobish guy trying to learn Java, and I'm having a little trouble completing a task I gave myself. Basicaly I'm trying to do the exercises at the end of this [page.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/creating-questions.html)

I managed to finish it with three classes. **The Card**:

```
public class Card {

public int nRank; // Used later
public int maxRank = 13; //The max number of Ranks
public int nSuit; // Used later
public int maxSuit = 4; // Max number of suits


//Associate both rank and suit numbers with strings

public String[] ranks = new String[maxRank - 1];
{
    ranks[0] = "two";
    ranks[1] = "three";
    ranks[2] = "four";
    ranks[3] = "five";
    ranks[4] = "six";
    ranks[5] = "seven";
    ranks[6] = "eight";
    ranks[7] = "nine";
    ranks[8] = "ten";
    ranks[9] = "Jack";
    ranks[10] = "Queen";
    ranks[11] = "King";
    ranks[12] = "Ace";

    }

public String[] suits = new String[maxSuit - 1];
{
    suits[0] = "Clubs";
    suits[1] = "Diamonds";
    suits[2] = "Spades";
    suits[3] = "Hearts";
    }

public String suit = suits[nSuit]; //The suit string of the card whose suit number is nSuit
public String rank = ranks[nRank]; //Same but with ranks

//Constructor for the Card object, with two arguments, x for rank, y for suit
public Card(int x,int y){
    this.nRank = x;
    this.nSuit = y;
}

//method to get which card it is in a string
public String whatCard(){
    return rank + " of " + suit;
}
}
```

**The Deck:**

```
    public class Deck {

public static int nRanks = 13; //number of ranks
public static int nSuits = 4; // number of suits
public static int nCard = nRanks * nSuits; // number of cards

Card[] deck = new Card[nCard -1]; //new array called deck to store all the cards 
int h = 0; //a variable to control the place of each card in the array
//constructor for the Deck
public Deck() {

while(h < 52){ // loop until there are 52 cards

// cycles through all the possible combinations between i(ranks) and j(suits) and creates a card with each
for(int i = 1; i <= nRanks; i++){

    for(int j = 1; j <= nSuits; j++){

        deck[h] = new Card(i,j); // creation of the card
        h++; // adds 1 to to h so the program knows how many cards are there
        }
    }

}
}
//method for getting a card depending on its position in the array(x)
    public Card getCard(int x){
    return deck[x-1];   
}
}
```

And the displayer of the cards/deck, which I called **Shuffle**:

```
public class Shuffle {

public static void main(String[] args){
        Deck newDeck = new Deck(); // creates a new Deck object
        //loops through all the cards in the deck
    for(int i = 0; i < Deck.nCard; i++){
        System.out.println(newDeck.getCard(i).whatCard()); // prints each card
    }

}
```

}

Although eclipse doesn't notice any errors in the code, when I try to compile, I'm shown this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at Card.<init>(Card.java:26)
    at Deck.<init>(Deck.java:20)
    at Shuffle.main(Shuffle.java:5)
```

What have I missed?

Comment: What you are seeing is an exception and Eclipse won't be able to predict those. The text you are seeing is called a stack trace and it marks where the exception was caused at. The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptoin means that you tried to access an array's element that didn't exist. This means that the 12th position in the array does not exist.

Comment: As an alternative, consider [`Card`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ranks[] and suits[] have both indexes from 0 to 12.

you're trying to access from 1 to 13 (in your for loop)

Use this code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < nRanks; i++){

    for(int j = 0; j < nSuits; j++){

        deck[h] = new Card(i,j); // creation of the card
        h++; // adds 1 to to h so the program knows how many cards are there
    }
}
```

EDIT :

I noticed another error, the one who generate the out of bounds :
In your Card class, change this lines :

```
public String[] ranks = new String[maxRank - 1];
public String[] suits = new String[maxSuit - 1];
```

by

```
public String[] ranks = new String[maxRank];
public String[] suits = new String[maxSuit];
```

When you create an array, you don't specify the last index, but the place avaible. So if you wanna put 13 values, specify new String[13].

---

EDIT : the full Deck class :

```
public class Deck {

   public static int nRanks = 13;  
   public static int nSuits = 4; 
   public static int nCard = nRanks * nSuits; 

   Card[] deck = new Card[nCard]; //nCard indexes, not nCard - 1

   public Deck() {
      //remove the while, double loop useless
      for(int i = 0; i < nRanks; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < nSuits; j++){
            deck[j * nRanks + i] = new Card(i,j);
         }
      }
   }

   public Card getCard(int x){
      return deck[x-1];   
   }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't even get that far... It bombs upon attempting to fill the arrays in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much! The exception is finally gone and I fill even noobier for messing up the arrays so bad. But Jeff is right, it fails the filling of the arrays, printing only two's of clubs. If it's not asking too much, why's that?

Comment: Didn't noticed it, but there were 2 loops (a while and a for). The for loop already creates your 52 cards, you don't need to make a while loop over it. See my new edit for the fuul Deck class

Comment: While the j * nRanks + i solution is very clever, it doesn't seem to solve my problem, as the program still prints exclusively twos of clubs.
One thing I noticed was the exception on the return deck[x-1]; but I removed the -1 and it went back to normal.

Comment: Ow sorry, I found it. In your class Card, you always use the default value of rank and sign : `public String suit = suits[nSuit];`. You must move the assignment in the constructor. Here, nSuit is still 0, than your card will always use the 2 first values : '2' ans 'clubs'.

Comment: `public Card(int x,int y){
    this.nRank = x;
    this.nSuit = y;
    this.suit = suits[nSuit];
    this.rank = ranks[nRank];
}`

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to never assign their first value to your variables before the constructor (or only for static variables, as you'll see later), then you'll avoid many problems ;) And please set this question as answered if you're done with.

Answer (score 3):

In all your loops of length N, you're trying to access from elements 1..N. You should be looping from 0..(1-N).

For example if you have 4 suits, you have an array with elements 0,1,2,3. By saying `(for j=1; j<=4, j++)`, you're trying to access element 4, which is out of bounds.

It should read `(j=0; j<4; j++)`.

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays are zero based... So creating a new array of 13 - 1 == 12 elements, but the array starts at zero meaning accessing element "12" is in effect the 13th element, thus an array out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 1):

In Card you have:

```
public int nRank; // Used later
public int maxRank = 13; //The max number of Ranks
public int nSuit; // Used later
public int maxSuit = 4; // Max number of suits
```

And then later

```
public String suit = suits[nSuit]; //The suit string of the card whose suit number is nSuit
public String rank = ranks[nRank]; //Same but with ranks
```

nSuit and nRank are not initialized to anything sane.  Try setting to something like 0.  However, I don't think that this is actually what you want, since suit and rank will be set at object construction time, and not as a result of your call to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

That error is occurring when you try to run it (not when you try to compile it).  This is a little picky, but it is good to get the terminology right.

The problem is that you're trying to get an element in the array with an index that is out of bounds.  In your array declarations (rank and suit) you use `max - 1`, while it should be `max`.  For example, `suits[3] = "Hearts"` is invalid, since `suits` is only of length 3 (`maxSuit -1` = 3).